# Do you know fast way to make screenshots for itunesconnect

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot, app-store-connect, simulator

Does anyone know the fastest way to create screenshots for iTunesConnect for different devices at the same time?

For: 
- 3.5 inch
- 4 inch
- 4.7 inch
- 5.5 inch
- iPad

Comment: Actually, that's what I asked about https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot/

Answer (score 2):

You can't create multiple screenshots because of the mismatched aspect ratio. Different devices have a different aspect ratio.

You could try running your app on the iOS Simulator:

[image]

And manually save the screenshots this way:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do this would be cmd+s from within the iOS Simulator. By default, screenshots are saved to the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2016, you only need to upload one set of screenshots for both 4.7- and 5.5-inch screen sizes.

You can simply drag and drop your screenshots to each device family separately or click “Use 5.5-inch Display”

For screenshots editing, I am using [ShotBot](https://shotbot.io) to save my time.

refs: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08082016a&1470700182